# Scala Comparing Values in 2 Spark Dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to write a condition statement for joining 2 Spark dataframes together in Scala:

```
val joinCondition = when($"filteredRESULT.key" == $"allDataUSE.key" && $"allDataUSE.timestamp" >=  $"filteredRESULT.tripStart" && $"allDataUSE.timestamp" <= $"filteredRESULT.tripEND", $"allDataUSE.tripid" === $"filteredRESULT.tripid").otherwise($"allDataUSE.tripid" === 0)
```

The `filteredRESULT` df is very small, and includes a tripID, tripStart time, tripEnd time. My goal is to use `filteredRESULT` as a lookup table, where a row from the `allDataUSE` df is compared against the entries in `filteredRESULT`. For example:

If in `allDataUSE`, a row matches `filteredRESULT` key, a timestamp >= a trip's start time, and <= a trip's end time, then the `tripid` column in `allDataUSE` should receive the value of `tripid` in the `filteredRESULT` df.

I am getting a `boolean` error when I run the above conditional statement. How can I perform this operation? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Are getting The boolean error because where condition expect the condition to return boolean,but the operator === in spark return the column as ouput.becuase of that you are getting that error.

below i am sharing the link to spark document you see that.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

```
public Column equalTo(Object other)
Equality test.

   // Scala:
   df.filter( df("colA") === df("colB") )

   // Java
   import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
   df.filter( col("colA").equalTo(col("colB")) );

Parameters:
other - (undocumented)
Returns:
(undocumented)
```

so remove that === and replace with == it work